# Сохранение данных в дополнительном окне JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть основная сцена в которой есть кнопка для открытия другой сцены, для подсчёта данных и комментариев. Вопрос: Как при закрытии другой сцены и открытии её позже сохранить в ней данные которые ранее были введены, то-есть что бы они не удалялись.

Comment: Сохранить в файл. При открытия прочитать из файла.

Answer (score 0):

1. Попробуйте сохранить результат fxmloader.load и fxmlloader.getController() и при вызове другой сцены подставлять уже имеющиеся результаты
2. При вызове сцены достать из fxmlolader контроллер и передавать нужные значения
3. При вызове сцены достать из fxmlolader и пнуть его, что он забрал сохраненные значения их мета их хранения.

Напишите, если по какому-то из вариантов надо более развернуто ответить.